# JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, jquery, deserialization

I think I have isolated the problem but I don't know how to solve it. I'm implementing filters for my jQuery grid and when I pass the filter data to the server I get this `unrecognized escape sequence` error.

This is the data that I send to server:

```
[{"field":"Code","op":"na","data":""},
{"field":"UserId","op":"na","data":"Name\Jim"},
{"field":"Name","op":"na","data":""}]
```

I didn't get this error until I send `{"field":"UserId","op":"na","data":"Name\Jim"},` and the only character that may cause such kind of problem in my opinion is the backslash in `"Name\Jim"`.

I got this error here:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request["filters"]))
{
      string jsonString = request["filters"];
      filter.Rules = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FilterRule[]>(jsonString);
}
```

And more exactly from here - `filter.Rules = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FilterRule[]>(jsonString);`.

I guess I have to escape this slash somehow somewhere. I wonder where is the right place to do it and is it possible to do it server side during deserialization if that's the problem of course?

P.S

This is the jQuery part where I prepare the filter data :

```
filter.push({ field: 'UserId', op: 'na', data: $('#cboFilterUser').val() });
```

Maybe I could escape it here?

P.S P.S

Ok, I find some solution that works for now :

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request["filters"]))
            {
                string jsonString = request["filters"];
                jsonString = jsonString.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
                filter.Rules = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FilterRule[]>(jsonString);
            }
```

This part : `jsonString = jsonString.Replace(@"\", @"\\");` but I see it more like work around than a real solution. Please comment is this a good idea and what could possibly go wrong if I leave it like that.

Comment: do you really need to use `javascripserializer`?

Comment: Your json has problem with "\"

Comment: If you put this jason to json validator it will not parse it.

Comment: Can you try hardcoding '\' to '\\' at the location where this 'filter' is set? Just to see if it will work and confirm that backslash is really sent as a character, not some control char

Comment: @aiapatag Yeah, it would be much more easier if I can escape the character instead of changing the business logic.

Comment: Ozren Tkalčec Krznarić is absolutely right

Comment: @kostas ch I populate the dropdown from database, how can I make it valid after that?

Comment: Try to use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strIn); (if it is possible) when you retrive your data from database and before populate them.

Comment: @Ozren Tkalčec Krznarić maybe your right, I try this: `filter.push({ field: 'UserId', op: 'na', data: "Name\\Jim" });` and this - `filter.push({ field: 'UserId', op: 'na', data: "Name\\\Jim" });`. I read that I have to use two backslashes to escape something in  jQuery so I tried `\\` and `\\\` but got the same error. Am I escaping it wrong or it's really something else that cause the problem?

Comment: Well, in fact I had to use 4 backslashes `"Name\\\\Jim"` but that way I escape it both client and server side and I don't get error, so I think it's the slash after all, but if I just escape it in the jQuery then C# recognize the slash as escaping symbol and throws this error.

Comment: did you try to use [JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx)?

Comment: @aiapatag just did - it breaks the whole Json, adds slashes everywhere. Can't use it :(

Comment: Linq to Entities doesn't recognize it and if I try your suggestion I get an error, any idea how to solve this? I try this : ` var UsersList = context.Documents.Select(d => new
            {
                UserId = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(d.UserId)
            });`

Comment: you need to escape that Name\Jim from the moment you got it before converting it to JSON.